# Image Randomization using GD library

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I have been tasked with a problem where i need to pickup one image froma  set of 1000 and serve it to the user based on the parameters passed in the get query.
This was simple.
Adiditonally, i have been asked to serve the image in such a way that even if the same file is server everytime, the sha1 hash of the image file should come different.

To achieve this,We could just add random pixels in the image background at random places.

Can somebody tell me how i can acheive this using the GD library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Imagesetpixel](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php).

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('your_image.png');
$red = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0); 
imagesetpixel($img, $x, $y, $red);
........
........
```

On the other hand why would you want to change the sha1 hash of the image on every request?

Edit: Since you want a transparent pixel, you are going to need [imagealphablending](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagealphablending.php) and something like this:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('your_image.png');
imagealphablending($img, false);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagesetpixel($img, $x, $y, $transparent);
imagesavealpha($img, true);         
imagepng($img, 'my_saved_file.png');
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to add a transparent pixel instead of a red coloured dot! How would i do that?  The requirement has come to me from my boss, so i am not sure why he needs that feature

Comment: Hi i tried using the code provided by you.Unfrotunately, the transparent pixels are appearing as black dots on the image.Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: can you provide a sample image?

Comment: hey-i will have to upload the code to a test server! may take some time. the image that i am currently using is a gif image.Would that be an issue for the black spots?

Comment: I basically need a way to emned random data in the image.Image can be either of gif/png/jpeg. If transparent pixels are not an answer can you suggest another way to have random data inside the image without affecting the display quality of the image?

Comment: You could turn your images to jpg and add random [Exif](http://lsolesen.github.com/pel/) data.